# ibm domino want to save big xml string in to rich text field but getting limit error

Tags: java, xml, lotus-domino

I have a java agent in which i receive an xml.
This I convert to string and then want to save in a Rich Text field(which is editable):

```
RequestDoc.replaceItemValue("XmlTU",sb.toString());
```

But then I receive this error:

NotesException: Notes error: Field is too large (32K) or View's column & selection formulas are too large

Could it be that notes sees the xml string as one paragraph?
Because rich text fields paragraphs have limit of 64K?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use RichTextItem's method [appendText()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_APPENDTEXT_METHOD_JAVA.html) instead:

```
  RichTextItem rtitem = RequestDoc.createRichTextItem("XmlTU");
  rtitem.appendText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Is it also possible to recover the old document because i cant open it, it gives me an error with field is too large (32K)

Comment: Not that I know of, unfortunately. Probably, you can't even delete the document. The solution might be `load compact -c` or creating a new replica to get rid of the document.

Comment: I'm not up on later versions, but you may still need to be careful with putting large chunks of xml into rich text fields. Unless it's been fixed, Domino will silently put in a paragraph break if you run over 32k with a large string and it may do that at any point in your xml, potentially breaking it.